How can I send an answer to a crypto question which has been closed?
I got another answer for Looking for C++/Python Open Source code library for cryptanalysis of classical ciphers ?
Can I add this besides the question was closed?
Or is there a way to get in contact with the author?

The best thing to do would be to get the question migrated to a different site (you should suggest where) or to ask the question again in a more appropriate place and give your answer there.
Since the question was deemed off-topic on this site neither the question nor the answer should be here. That's why you cannot add your answer.

Software Recommendations SE should probably take this Q. Also note that OP can't flag posts yet due to lack of reputation.

@SEJPM: Yes, it looks like it could be on-topic at software recs (although I'm not actually a regular there, so I could be mistaken). That specific question is too old to migrate, though, so the best we could do is delete it here (which we probably should do anyway; it does nobody any good in its current closed state) and let somebody repost it there.

@IlmariKaronen Dropped in my vote to confirm yours. It's gone. ;)
